# Can we deploy the `Data Category Groups` and its related categories ? If yes, then under which component of the Change Set will it come?

Tags: change-set, data-category

Can we deploy the `Data Category Groups` and its related categories ?
If yes, then under which component of the Change Set will it come ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can use change sets and salesforce recommends a manual migration.

Using Metadata API to deploy category changes from one organization to another permanently removes categories and record categorizations that are not specified in your XML file. Salesforce.com recommends that you manually create data categories.
use the [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_datacategorygroup.htm#dcg_usage)

Comment: Yes, it does not appear to be supported in change sets. A tool using the metadata API can do it such as the SF deployment tool, Eclipse, Workbench, etc.